# слои Service Repository BestPractices Spring

Tags: java, spring, service, repository, best-practice

интересует момент: для каждого репозитори - свой сервис? И потом уже создавать общий сервис, связывая другие сервисы, или же, все таки можно использовать в одном сервисе несколько разных репозиториев? Может есть у спринга какие-то офф доки для этого?

Answer (score 0):

У самого Spring вряд ли есть какой-то гайд по этому вопросу. Тут надо руководствоваться здравым смыслом. Как правило, сначала пишешь "всё в кучу", пока не заработает как надо (желательно еще тестами все сдобрить). Потом как всё заработало, смотришь на всё это и рефакторишь, чтоб было "красиво" (при этом чтоб тесты не падали). Не плодите сущностей без набобности и будет Вам счастье. А лучше почитайте "Чистый код" Боба Мартина.

Comment: Помните анекдот про "вы либо крестик снимите"? У вас начало ответа "фигачь как получится", а потом "чистый код". Предлагаю рассказать, как полагается делать по книгам дядюшки Боба - ведь фигачить как получится это тривиальный совет.